# How to pass multiple arguments into function

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse a json file, Suppose the function that is called takes in the json path from a variable called `section1`

```
def traverseJson(arg1):
    #do stuff

section1 = json["section"]["section"][1]
```

To call the function I'd run:

```
traverseJson(section1)
```

How would I then pass in multiple arguments into the function? e.g

```
section2 = json["section"]["subsection"][0]
section3 = json["section"]["subsection"][0]
```

A solution which does not predefine the number of arguments will be more suitable as the number of arguments can vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `*args` syntax:

```
def traverse(*args):
    for arg in args:
        # logic
```

---

**UPDATE: Usage**

```
section1 = ...
section2 = ...
traverse(section1, section2)

# or

sections = [..., ...]
traverse(*sections)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass this kind of arguments as an array or as a dictionary (keyword map).

To pass as an array use `*` operator, to pass as a hash, use `**` operator.

Example:

```
def function(first_arg, *args, **kwargs): 
  # something
```

Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the maximum number of args an un-pythonic way of doing it would be

```
def traverseJson(arg1=0, arg2=0, arg3=0, arg4=0):
```

If four arguments aren't given it just assigns 0 to the remaining variables.

However, I would recommend passing the arguments as a list. e.g.

```
def traverseJson(arg1) :
    for i in arg1:
        #do stuff

traverseJson([section1, section2, section3])
```

Hope this helps